# Why does this XPath expression work for one node but not the other?

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

I have a function that retrieves the `.InnerText` for an attribute in an XML node:

```
    string getPropertyFromNode_string(XmlNode node, string propertyName)
    {
        try
        {
            string selectString = "./empty:content/m:properties/d:";
            return node.SelectSingleNode(selectString + propertyName, Utils.nmREST).InnerText;
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(exception.Message);
            throw exception;
        }
    }
```

`nmREST` is defined in the constructor of a static `Utils` class as follows:

```
    public static XmlNamespaceManager nmREST = new XmlNamespaceManager(new NameTable());

    static Utils()
    {
        nmREST.AddNamespace("d", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices");
        nmREST.AddNamespace("m", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata");
        nmREST.AddNamespace("empty", "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom");
        nmREST.AddNamespace("z", "#RowsetSchema");
    }
```

I test the function on this XmlNode:

```
<entry m:etag="&quot;81&quot;" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
    <id>Web/Lists(guid'someguid')/Items(1213)</id>
    <category term="SP.Data.LibItem" scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme" />
    <link rel="edit" href="Web/Lists(guid'someguid')/Items(1213)" />
    <title />
    <updated>2019-04-16T06:16:50Z</updated>
    <author>
        <name />
    </author>
    <content type="application/xml">
        <m:properties>
            <d:Id m:type="Edm.Int32" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices">1213</d:Id>
            <d:FileLeafRef xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices">myfile.xlsm</d:FileLeafRef>
            <d:FeatureCount m:type="Edm.Double" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices">33</d:FeatureCount>
            <d:Status xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices">Production Ready</d:Status>
            <d:CheckoutUserId m:null="true" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices" />
            <d:EditorId m:type="Edm.Int32" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices">25</d:EditorId>
            <d:ID m:type="Edm.Int32" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices">1213</d:ID>
        </m:properties>
    </content>
</entry>
```

using this function call:

```
getPropertyFromNode_string(thisNode,"ID")
```

and the value `1213` is successfully retrieved.

However, when I test it on the following XmlNode:

```
<entry m:etag="&quot;24&quot;" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
    <id>Web/Lists(guid'someguid')/Items(1422)</id>
    <category term="SP.Data.LibItem" scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme" />
    <link rel="edit" href="Web/Lists(guid'someguid')/Items(1422)" />
    <link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/Station" type="application/atom+xml;type=entry" title="Station" href="Web/Lists(guid'someguid')/Items(1422)/Station">
        <m:inline>
            <entry>
                <id>anotherguid</id>
                <category term="SP.Data.DifferentLibItem" scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme" />
                <title />
                <updated>2019-04-16T05:58:17Z</updated>
                <author>
                    <name />
                </author>
                <content type="application/xml">
                    <m:properties>
                        <d:FacilityNumber xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices">1068</d:FacilityNumber>
                    </m:properties>
                </content>
            </entry>
        </m:inline>
    </link>
    <title />
    <updated>2019-04-16T05:58:17Z</updated>
    <author>
        <name />
    </author>
    <content type="application/xml">
        <m:properties>
            <d:FileLeafRef xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices">thatfilename.xlsm</d:FileLeafRef>
            <d:Title m:null="true" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices" />
        </m:properties>
    </content>
</entry>
```

using the function call:

```
getPropertyFromNode_string(thisNode,"FacilityNumber")
```

then the `SelectSingleNode()` call throws an exception with the message:

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

I guess this means that the XPath expression isn't successfully locating the `<d:FacilityNumber>` element, so there's no object to get `InnerText` from.  Why isn't the element being found?  What's different about the second node's XML structure, and what XPath expression should I be using instead?

Comment: path to Facility number is not the same as the Id :-)

Comment: @LaurentLequenne i don't understand; both are inside `<content><m:properties></m:properties></content>`, how should the path be different for `FacilityNumber`?

Comment: one is in <entry><m:inline><entry><content><m:properties>

Comment: Ok, so the XPath should be `./empty:link/m:inline/empty:entry/empty:content/m:properties/d:`.  I verified that this works.  If you want to post that as the answer I'll accept it.

Comment: no worries, man :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per Laurent Lequenne's comment on the OP, including the full nesting sequence of child nodes in the XPath expression successfully retrieves the desired child node, as follows:

```
./empty:link/m:inline/empty:entry/empty:content/m:properties/d:
```